# How can I know the account team members of my parent account?

Tags: administration, account, account-teams

> Sharing settings for Accounts: Private, with grant access using
>   hierarchies

As the owner, or in the account team, of an account, I wouldn't mind knowing who are the team members of my parent account, just in case I need to talk to them for advice. The parent account would probably be owned by a superior in the role hierarchy.

After switching to my administrator credentials, how can I quickly configure Salesforce so that standard users know the names of account team members of parent accounts?

If it doesn't seem likely to be achievable by quick configuration, what approximate solutions sound good?

Comment: Would you want to automatically add those team members to all teams below the parent account? Otherwise, using Dashboards running under his credentials in a folder available to all his subordinates, the manager could share that info with his subordinates.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev, no I won't need to automatically add those team members, just seeing is good enough.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need `VisualForce`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `apex:relatedList` [component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:relatedList list="AccountTeamMembers" subject="{!Account.Parent_Account__c}" />
</apex:page>
```